# How to draw a line in R on a blank sheet of a defined length?

Tags: r, line

I am searching for a command to draw a line in R on a blank sheet of defined length. For example a line that is exactly 2.55 cm long.
Does anyone know if there is such a tool?

Comment: This question could use more detail. Are you planning on printing out an image, or generating a pdf, or operating a pen plotter, or what?

Comment: Yes I am planning th print them out, on a A4 paper. So Best would be if the printed line has exactly the defined length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will write a pdf comprising a single A4 page with a 2.55cm line drawn on it 10cm from the bottom of the page:

```r
library(grid)

pdf('mypdf.pdf', width = 8.25, height = 11.75)

grid.newpage()
line <- linesGrob(x = unit(c(10, 12.55), 'cm'), y = unit(c(10, 10), 'cm'))
grid.draw(line)

dev.off()
```

Comment: What i do not get is how to specify the length if i want a different length

Comment: The x and y co-ordinates are in cm, so if you want a 3cm line you would change `c(10, 12.55)` to `c(10, 13)`. (Note the difference between the first and second numbers). The first number is where the line starts, the second is where it ends.

Comment: There is just something left: If i print it, the lines are not that exact length. Is it possible that the lines are compressed when writing into a pdf?

Comment: Is it maybe linked to the fact that width and height of the pdf are given in inches and lenght of line in cm?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the units, as these are all converted internally. Are you printing full page without borders?

Comment: You might me right, just changed it in adobe acrobate reader to "real size", then it seems to work better.

Comment: If i want to adjust the line width; why does width as an argument in linesGrob not work? Is there a possibility to adjust the width?